# Подcчет количества циклов while Java

Tags: java

Полный новичок, не пойму как мне подсчитать количество мат. операций в while(т.е. количество циклов) и вывести в конце в sout, помогите, пожалуйста.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        long value = scanner.nextLong();
        while (true) {
            System.out.println(value);
            if (value % 2 == 0) {
                value /= 2;
            } else {
                value = 3 * value + 1;
            }
            if (value == 1) {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: Объявляете переменную-счётчик перед циклом, в цикле инкрементируете, выводите значение после цикла.  Какие с этим проблемы?

Comment: @Nowhere Man попахивает лёгкими +15 к репе 

Comment: @ScruffytheJanitor, для автора вопроса важнее было бы попытаться написать данный код самостоятельно

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        long value = scanner.nextLong(); 
 int i = 0; //  счетчик
        while (true) {
             i++; //  увеличить счётчик при каждой итерации 
System.out.println(value);
            if (value % 2 == 0) {
                value /= 2;
            } else {
                value = 3 * value + 1;
            }
            if (value == 1) {
                break;
            }
        }
System.out.println("количество итераций - "+i);
    }
}
```

С телефона пишу поэтому может где-то ошибка

Comment: Спасибо, даже не подумал что так можно :с

Comment: @Александр вы ещё не раз себе это скажите в процессе изучения, в этом весь кайф, когда что-то сложное на первый взгляд оказывается чем-то простым или очевидным